# Need assistance checking to see if a value is -1

Tags: java, android, eclipse, null, nullpointerexception

I need to check to see if a value is -1. I'm having trouble with a bit of source code I've compiled and I'm not sure how to resolve the issue for [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15843824/issues-passing-data-from-nfc-tag-reader-to-wifi-manager).

I know I need to implement:

```
if(wifiManager.addNetwork(conf) == -1) {
    // Insert code to handle the failure here.
} else {
    // The rest of your code for the 'success' case here!
}
```

but I'm not sure what I should insert to handle the failure.

Comment: While posting a question, you should not assume that anyone knows anything, So you should ask anything as much as clear as you can!

Comment: Really?  This question displays a total lack of knowledge of Java basics.  You should STOP CODING NOW, and read the Oracle Java Tutorial ... or any good Java text book.

Comment: StackExchange is NOT a substitute for reading a text book / doing a tutorial, attending your lectures.

Comment: I've followed two tutorials - both work successfully - but when I'm attempting to pass data between them - I'm having an issue.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it by comparing the result of `wifiManager.addNetwork(conf);` in an `if` statement...

```
if(wifiManager.addNetwork(conf) == -1) {
    // Insert code to handle the failure here.
} else {
    // The rest of your code for the 'success' case here!
}
```

I'm assuming you are working with [Android's `WiFiManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html#addNetwork%28android.net.wifi.WifiConfiguration%29).

Comment: I am - I'm having trouble with the following issue:


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15843824/issues-passing-data-from-nfc-tag-reader-to-wifi-manager

Comment: If I am being asked to check to see if it return -1 should this be accomplished with log.d?

Comment: I'm just not sure if I understand the users question "does wifiManager.addNetwork(conf); return -1"

I'm really not sure what I'm being asked

Comment: The comment to your original question is asking if the call to `addNetwork` is failing. Check the API [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html#addNetwork(android.net.wifi.WifiConfiguration). The docs say it "Returns -1 on failure.", hence the comment. Todd has answered your question, if you do not understand that, this tutorial you are using is far too advanced for you, and you need some beginner's tutorials.